# Chart.js Treemap Adding custom text to each rectangle

Tags: javascript, html, graph, chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

I am using chart.js to develop a TreeMap. It works great but the issue is each rectangle only shows the value of the data. I want to add some custom text next to the value. How do I achieve this?

```
var topTags = [
  {tag:'python',num:133269},{tag:'javascript',num:109742},{tag:'java',num:65490},{tag:'c#',num:45445},{tag:'html',num:43767},{tag:'android',num:42657},{tag:'reactjs',num:38844},{tag:'php',num:34381},{tag:'sql',num:29996},{tag:'python',num:29942},{tag:'css',num:29654},{tag:'r',num:28319},{tag:'c++',num:27389},{tag:'node.js',num:25415},{tag:'angular',num:24093},{tag:'pandas',num:23826},{tag:'arrays',num:23075},{tag:'jquery',num:18968},{tag:'mysql',num:18863},{tag:'swift',num:17971},{tag:'ios',num:17600},{tag:'json',num:15589},{tag:'laravel',num:15537},{tag:'flutter',num:15201},{tag:'c',num:15195},{tag:'django',num:14748},{tag:'sql',num:12752},{tag:'reactjs',num:10974},{tag:'excel',num:10962},{tag:'list',num:10726},{tag:'regex',num:10676}
];

var canvas = document.getElementById("treemap");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var chart = window.chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: "treemap",
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      tree: topTags,
      key: "num",
      groups: ['num'],
      spacing: 0.5,
      borderWidth: 1.5,
      fontColor: "black",
      borderColor: "grey"
    }]
  },
  options: {
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    legend: { display: false },
    tooltips: { enabled: false }
  }
});
```

When running this code, I get the numbers in each rectangle but I need some text to be appended next to the numbers for each rectangle. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `formatter` options in the `labels` section:

```js
const options = {
  type: 'treemap',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      tree: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      backgroundColor: 'pink',
      labels: {
        display: true,
        formatter(ctx) {
          const data = ctx.chart.data;
          return `Custom Text: ${data.datasets[ctx.datasetIndex].tree[ctx.dataIndex]}`;
        }
      },
    }]
  },
  options: {}
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.0/chart.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-chart-treemap@2.0.1/dist/chartjs-chart-treemap.js"></script>
</body>
```